# hyperledger fabric2.2.1, when I install the chaincode from asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java, I failed ! why?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

fabric2.2.1, when I install the chaincode from asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java, I failed ! why?
and why the docs for v2.2.1  don't have the java tutorials?? please help me to figure out,thanks!!

Here are the code errors I encountered :

cyj@cyj-ubuntu:~/go/src/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java/ --lang java --label basic_1.0
cyj@cyj-ubuntu:~/go/src/fabric-samples/test-network$ peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image build failed: docker build failed: Error returned from build: 1 "+ INPUT_DIR=/chaincode/input

- OUTPUT_DIR=/chaincode/output
  ++ mktemp -d
- TMP_DIR=/tmp/tmp.faBNpJ
  ++ find /chaincode/input -name .jar
  ++ paste -s -d : -
- JARS=
  ++ find /chaincode/input -name '*.jar'
  ++ wc -l
- NUM_JARS=1
- for DIR in ${INPUT_DIR} ${INPUT_DIR}/src
- '[' -f /chaincode/input/build.gradle -o -f /chaincode/input/build.gradle.kts ']'
- '[' -f /chaincode/input/pom.xml ']'
- for DIR in ${INPUT_DIR} ${INPUT_DIR}/src
- '[' -f /chaincode/input/src/build.gradle -o -f /chaincode/input/src/build.gradle.kts ']'
- buildGradle /chaincode/input/src /chaincode/output
- echo 'Copying from /chaincode/input/src to /tmp/tmp.faBNpJ'
- Copying from /chaincode/input/src to /tmp/tmp.faBNpJ
  cd /chaincode/input/src
- tar cf - .
- cd /tmp/tmp.faBNpJ
- tar xf -
- cd /tmp/tmp.faBNpJ
- echo 'Gradle build'
  Gradle build
- '[' -f ./gradlew ']'
- chmod +x ./gradlew
- ./gradlew build shadowJar -x test
  Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5.1-bin.zip
  .................................................................................................

Welcome to Gradle 6.5.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:

- Experimental file-system watching
- Improved version ordering
- New samples

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/6.5.1/release-notes.html

Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'shadowJar' not found in root project 'basic'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
"

Comment: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-java/build.gradle  this is the build.gradle.

Comment: anyone know how to fix it, please help!

Comment: is it because the shadowjar？？ what should I do to fix it?